# Android Studio - GoogleAPIClient deprecated fix

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, google-api, deprecated

I am building a GPS app, but GoogleAPIClient is deprecated and I'm not sure how to fix it. Also when I run the app, I get a sign-in button that doesn't lead to anything, which may be related to this since I know that GoogleSignInClient exists. Also, if you could link me to a more detailed explanation of GoogleApi I would really appreciate it!

```
public static final String MA = "MainActivity";
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private GoogleApiClient gac;
    private Location location;
    private TextView locationTV;
    private TextView distanceTV;
    private TextView addressET;
    private TextView timeLeftTV;
    private String destinationAddress = "";
    private TravelManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_tv);
        manager = new TravelManager();
        addressET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destination_et);
        distanceTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_tv);
        timeLeftTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_left_tv);


        gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    public void updateTrip(View v) {
        String address = addressET.getText().toString();
        boolean goodGeoCoding = true;
        if (!address.equals(destinationAddress)) {
            destinationAddress = address;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(destinationAddress, 5);
                if (address != null) {
                    double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                    double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
                    Location destinationLocation = new Location("destination");
                    destinationLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
                    destinationLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
                    manager.setDestination(destinationLocation);
                }
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                goodGeoCoding = false;
            }
        }

        FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location current = fusedLocationProviderApi.getLastLocation(gac);
        if (current != null && goodGeoCoding) {
            distanceTV.setText(manager.milesToDestination(current));
            timeLeftTV.setText(manager.timeToDestination(current));
        }
    }

    public void displayLocation() {
        FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        location = fusedLocationProviderApi.getLastLocation(gac);

        if (location != null) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            locationTV.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
            Log.w(MA, "latutude = " + latitude + "; longitude = " + longitude);
        }else
            locationTV.setText("Error locating the device");
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle hint) {
        Log.w(MA, "connected");
        displayLocation();
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.w(MA, "connection suspended");
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.w(MA, "connection failed");
        if (result.hasResolution()){
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE);
            }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendIntentException) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Google Play services problem, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            gac.connect();
        }
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (gac != null)
            gac.connect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your concern for reference related to Google API, this API might help you with your GPS app needs.

[Location and Context APIs](https://developers.google.com/location-context?hl=en)

- The location and context APIs harness the sensors and signals of mobile devices to provide awareness of user actions and their environment, enabling delightful and engaging experiences that simplify user interactions, provide assistance, and help users to better understand themselves.
- This contains a list of APIs' and Platforms that you can use depending on what you are looking for.

In your case, you may check the following:

1. Places API

   Give your users contextual information about where they are, when they’re there. Access detailed information about 100 million places across a wide range of categories.
2. Geofencing

   Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest.
3. Fused Location Provider API
   Get location data for your app based on combined signals from the device sensors using a battery-efficient API.

---

> 

---

[Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/overview)

- Before you start using the Places API, you need a project with a billing account and the Places API enabled. (Please refer to the link on how to create a project with billing account)
- You need to [get an API key](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) that will authenticate you request.
- For more details regarding this API, you can visit the link provided.

The following place requests are available:

**Place Search** returns a list of places based on a user's location or search string.

**Place Details** returns more detailed information about a specific place, including user reviews.

**Place Photos** provides access to the millions of place-related photos stored in Google's Place database.

**Place Autocomplete** automatically fills in the name and/or address of a place as users type.

**Query Autocomplete** provides a query prediction service for text-based geographic searches, returning suggested queries as users type.

---

> 

---

[Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider)

The fused location provider is one of the location APIs in Google Play services. It manages the underlying location technology and provides a simple API so that you can specify requirements at a high level, like high accuracy or low power. It also optimizes the device's use of battery power.

Support for common location scenarios:

- [Last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)

  Includes step-by-step procedures to setup and access fused location provider
- Location settings
- Location updates

You can explore this reference to learn more:
https://developer.android.com/training/location